# Best/simplest say to allow non-admin to update/install software & move files around?

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator, administration

I have a small team of people who are all on Windows 10 machines. We work in video production, and as such we're quite often updating software, plugins, installing scripts into the Adobe programs etc.

All the team (except me) are only standard users, so currently whenever there's an update or they need to install a script etc I either go to their computer to approve admin access, or access their computers remotely to enter the password that way.

However this can get quite tiresome and take up a good part of my day, especially since its only a very small part of my job role.

I'm hoping there's an easier/quicker way to do this, while still keeping them as standard users?

*dreaming* Maybe something like the Microsoft Authenticator app would send me a notification when admin access was needed and I'd just click approve to allow it or something.

I know that's not possible, but is there a better alternative to what I'm already doing?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a domain? Use any of the many patch management systems out there to make your job easier.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a domain, every user has their own local accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no domain your options are very limited.

Personally, I would either allow admin rights for every local user and just make sure all the protections (UAC, Firewall, Antivirus, automated patching, etc) are turned on and focus on good education, or I would give each person a separate admin account and check logs from time to time to make sure they are not using it as their "daily driver".

There are patch management solutions that work for home users that can probably be pre-configured with local admin credentials, but I haven't worked with these in a long time and so do not have one to recommend. You may consider posting a question over at [Software Recommendations SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) for patch management solutions that work with the products you use and can work in a non-Domain environment.